# Filtrar um array de objetos conforme campo

Tags: php

Fazendo isso:

```
$total_tipo = $this->chamado->contagem('tipo');

        foreach ($total_tipo as $total_tip){

            print_r($total_tip);
        }
```

Estou obtendo esse resultado

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tipo] => 1
    [quantidade] => 85
)
stdClass Object
(
    [tipo] => 2
    [quantidade] => 492
)
stdClass Object
(
    [tipo] => 3
    [quantidade] => 147
)
stdClass Object
(
    [tipo] => 4
    [quantidade] => 1
)
```

Porém o que eu quero é exibir a quantidade de um tipo só, por exemplo:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tipo] => 1
    [quantidade] => 85
)
```

nesse caso só exibiria 85

para exibir todas quantidades faço isso

```
foreach ($total_tipo as $total_tip => $value){

                print_r($value->quantidade); 

        }
```

854911471

não consigo separar para que venha só a quantidade do tipo 1

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar a função [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para filtrar pelos registros que você deseja.

```
// Busca-se todos os registros
$total_tipo = $this->chamado->contagem('tipo');

// Filtra os do tipo 1
$tipo_1 = array_filter($total_tipo, function ($it) { return $it->tipo == 1; }); 

// Exibe apenas os registros de tipo 1
foreach ($tipo_1 as $value) {
    echo $value->quantidade;
}
```

Comment: $tipo_1 = array_filter($total_tipo, function ($it) { return $it->tipo == 1 }); está linha está com erro Message: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';'

Comment: @IsacDias Sim, está. Consegue me dizer o que é?

Comment: Sim tinha que fechar o return, valeu cara funcionou!